# Integrate authentication between asp net identity core and asp net 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to know how to integrate the authentication project which uses aspnet identity core with the API project which uses Web API and aspnet 4.6.1.

I have the following scenario:

- A Mobile app and an Angular 5 app that get the JWT token from the authentication project through web api.
- The Authentication project
- The API project where I get all needed data.

After getting the token, I want to be able validating the token when the API project receive it.

I tried to validate using the `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` on the startup of the API project.

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
   Authority = "https://localhost:44362"
});
```

But it shows me the following error:
`IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44362/.well-known/openid-configuration'.`

I don't have this endpoint on my project and I don't have the `/token` endpoint too.
The JWT token returns from the `/login` method I've created, where I send the user and password and then return the token.

**TLDR:**

How may I authenticate the user with the same JWT token received from the Auth project inside the API project?

Comment: Are you using IdentityServer or not? If you are, then you should be following one of the workflows it supports. Most likely hybrid for this particular scenario. Refer to the IdentityServer documentation.

Comment: No, I'm using aspnet core identity instead of the identity server. This is a separated project in the solution and I want to integrate the authentication with the API project.

Comment: You're not understanding. ASP.NET Identity is an auth provider/store. IdentityServer is also an auth provider/store (which can piggy-back on ASP.NET Identity, if you like). However, neither is what a client application would be using. For that, you're using the authentication/authorization handlers built in to ASP.NET Core. In an ASP.NET Core site with Identity, the handlers utilize Identity to auth, whereas with a distributed auth system like IdentityServer they're simply utilizing IdentityServer instead. You would not implement Identity on an IdentityServer client.

Comment: Let me see if I've got, correct if I'm wrong, please.
I'm using authentication/authorization handlers built in to ASP.NET Core but not the handlers identity uses, right?
So, in this case, do I need to use the identity server instead?

Comment: When you set up auth (separate from Identity setup), you have to define essentially what the provider it's using is. Identity plugs into that when you're using Identity. For IdentityServer, you'd just set it up to connect to that instead. You don't need Identity at all.